# I'm getting none type object when query a with sting

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

When I use this this query:

```
h = User.query.filter_by(id = 1).first()
print(h.name)
```

I get the result no problem. But when I use this query:

```
h = User.query.filter_by(name = 'jim').first()
print(h.id)
```

I get `NoneType` object

**EDIT:**

```
class bi_in(db.Model): 
    tablename = "bi_info" 
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True) 
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False) 
    number = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False) 
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False) 
    relate = db.relationship('pod_in', backref = 'bi', lazy = True )
```

Comment: Either the `attribute` or value you are trying to filter for i.e. `jim'` is not a valid value or doesn't exist in the database you are querying. verify those few things first.

Comment: Getting none type object when query with filter_by(name='jim')

Comment: gotcha. if it's only with that value filter, there could be some other issue. digged deeper into this, see this [link](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/), it's similar to your example.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

This means there are no entities in `User` with property `name` == 'jim'. Are you sure you don't mean `filter_by(username='jim')`?  Have you added the field `name` to the User class? Is "Jim" capitalized in the database?

I edited your question to add the code in your comment.  Your model is not called "User", but "bi_in".  Show your `User` model (by editing your question), or change your query to:

```
h = bi_in.query.filter_by(name = 'jim').first()
print(h.id)
```

Also, Classes in Python should have CamelCase Names, like `BiIn()`

Comment: no it's not username it's name. Does data end get capitalize

Comment: class bi_in(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "bi_info"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable = False)
    number = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable = False)
    relate = db.relationship('pod_in', backref = 'bi', lazy = True  )